# Pandas Groupby Based on Values in Multiple Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, cumsum

I have a `dataframe` that I am trying to use `pandas.groupby` on to get the cumulative sum. The values that I am grouping by show up in two different columns, and I am having trouble getting the groupby to work correctly. My starting `dataframe` is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_A': ['red', 'red', 'blue', 'red'], 'col_B': ['blue', 'red', 'blue', 'red'], 'col_A_qty': [1, 1, 1, 1], 'col_B_qty': [1, 1, 1, 1]})

col_A   col_B   col_A_qty   col_B_qty
red      blue      1           1
red      red       1           1
blue    blue       1           1
red      red       1           1
```

The result I am trying to get is:

```
col_A   col_B   col_A_qty   col_B_qty   red_cumsum  blue_cumsum
red     blue       1            1           1           1
red     red        1            1           3           1
blue    blue       1            1           3           3
red     red        1            1           5           3
```

I've tried:

```
df.groupby(['col_A', 'col_B'])['col_A_qty'].cumsum()
```

but this groups on the combination of `col_A` and `col_B`. How can I use `pandas.groupby` to calculate the cumulative sum of red and blue, regardless of if it's in `col_A` or `col_B`?

Comment: you can only do it one by one and sum it back ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try two `pivot`

```
out = pd.pivot(df,columns='col_A',values='col_A_qty').fillna(0).cumsum().add(pd.pivot(df,columns='col_B',values='col_B_qty').fillna(0).cumsum(),fill_value=0)
Out[404]: 
col_A  blue  red
0       1.0  1.0
1       1.0  3.0
2       3.0  3.0
3       3.0  5.0
df = df.join(out)
```

Comment: This works great, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is to define each `cumsum` column by two  [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), as follows:

```
df['red_cumsum'] = df['col_A'].eq('red').cumsum() + df['col_B'].eq('red').cumsum()
df['blue_cumsum'] = df['col_A'].eq('blue').cumsum() + df['col_B'].eq('blue').cumsum()
```

In each column `col_A` and `col_B`, check for values equal `'red'` / `'blue'` (results are boolean series). Then, we use [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) on these resultant boolean series to get the cumulative counts.  You don't really need to use `pandas.groupby` in this use case.

If you have multiple items in `col_A` and `col_B`, you can also iterate through the unique item list, as follows:

```
for item in np.unique(df[['col_A', 'col_B']]):
    df[f'{item}_cumsum'] = df['col_A'].eq(item).cumsum() + df['col_B'].eq(item).cumsum()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

  col_A col_B  col_A_qty  col_B_qty  red_cumsum  blue_cumsum
0   red  blue          1          1           1            1
1   red   red          1          1           3            1
2  blue  blue          1          1           3            3
3   red   red          1          1           5            3
```